# Alternatives to Remote Storage Service under Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I am working on setting up a new Windows Server 2008 R2 file server for our organization and felt like the functionality offered by the [Remote Storage Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816588) in previous versions of Windows would meet our needs for segmenting our data so that we can have different backup schedules for different tiers of data based on the frequency of that data being used and updated. Unfortunately this feature was removed from Server 2008 R2.

What software exists that provide this same or similar functionality for Server 2008 R2?